# Unable to connect to remote host using ssh

Tags: networking, fedora

I have recently installed Fedora in my system. But I am facing some problem in ssh login from remote machine.

I am able to login in that system but every time its requires me to login using GUI in that system. So if I reboot that system then after rebooting I won't be able to login until I go to that system and enter the password in GUI login.

Here I have notice that system connection checkbox is disabled in my system. So why is this option disabled in my system?

[image]

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

1) yeah sshd is running in both system

2) here is the output of `ssh -v login@machine' command

```
[root@localhost src]# ssh -v login@192.168.1.100
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.100 [192.168.1.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '192.168.1.100' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:23
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
login@192.168.1.100's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: This is really confused.  Do you have sshd running on the machine?  What does `ssh -v login@machine` gives you?  What do the log files say? Note that the GUI is utterly irrelevant to ssh and that the network configuration has nothing to do with ssh -- apart from enabling network.

Comment: @Sardathrion i am able to do ssh login after starting that system, but i need to provide the password everytime to that system.why system connection checkbox is disable in my system ?

Comment: You need to set up an ssh agent or ssk keys (in `~/.ssh/authorize_keys2`) if you do not wish to type your password all the time.  The `system connection` check box has nothing to do with ssh. It is a configuration of your network settings. Might I suggest you read up about networking in Linux and ssh in general. It will help you in the long run.

Comment: @Sardathrion Actually i have other same kind of system and in that system i never had this kind of problems.

Comment: Without knowing more about your settings on both system, I cannot comment further.

Comment: @Sardathrion what setting you want to know i'll give you each and every details to you !

Comment: As I said in my first comment: **Do you have sshd running on the machine? What does ssh -v login@machine gives you? What do the log files say?**

Comment: @Sardathrion see my edit

Comment: The question does not represent the real problem, do you want to connect password-less to SSH?

Comment: Is that `ssh -v` trace from when you can log in, or when you can't? When you can't log in, do you get a password prompt? Is this a wired or wifi connection? Is your home directory encrypted? Post your `/etc/sshd_config` (or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, whichever it is).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up [ssh public key authentication](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ssh%20private%20key&aq=f&oq=ssh%20private%20key&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.2484&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) if you do not want to type your password all the time.

As a side note, you should **never** use root as your personal account.  This is a terrible practice that will bite you sooner rather than later.  If you are attempting to login as root, then most sshd sane configurations will not allow that.  This is right behavior.

Comment: its not personal account, i am setting up all this thing on my server. and finally my problem is solved by setting `ONBOOT=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-p19p1` file.

Comment: @juned: This has *nothing* to do with ssh or what I understood your problem to be.

Comment: ohh i see but why now everything works fine

Comment: @juned: What works fine? ... You need to be more precise about what you are asking.  Currently, I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.  I thought it was passwordless ssh authentication.  It appears that now you are talking about setting your network interfaces. The two have **nothing** to do with each other in as much as ssh requires some networking.  Anyhow, 'nuff said.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with another user instead of root user ?
In latest fedora there is restriction for root. You can change it from
: /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: You *can* but *should not*. Allowing root access to ssh is like leaving you car unlocked with the keys in the ignition...